# If I combine my windows 7 pc and a dedicated VM ubuntu server, will this jeopardize my pc?

Tags: windows-7, security, microsoft-virtual-pc, ubuntu-server, combine

I've googled the internet and haven't been able to find a clear answer.  Mostly because people keep their dedicated servers separate from their pc, let alone run it in a virtual machine.  So in what ways would this jeopardize my system?  When I say jeopardize I mean my server slowing down to a crawl, I'll have more viruses to worry about, my pc will slow down, registry get messed up, configuration issues, overheat, and etc...

Extra details:  Would be running windows 7 OS on a 500gb SSD, The dedicated virtual server's OS will be ubuntu server edition using the VM "VirtualBox" and installed onto a 1tb HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no, unless you bork the design.  Fundamentally this isn't an Ubuntu or Windows issue: it boils down to whether running apps A and B at the same time leads to problems.  It doesn't matter if A and B are operating systems running inside a VM, or one is a host OS and one is a guest in a VM container, etc etc.

The only way they will interfere is if you let them:
- don't assign adequate resources to one or the other
- let one have access to files that should really only be seen by the other
- make one aware of the other

For example, if you were to run both on the same HD, that would be bad, because they would contend for disk access.  Or if you let the Windows box mount/access the file systems of the Ubuntu one (either directly or via network shares, say).  Or if you put both on the same IP subnet and did not firewall between the two in your host OS.

There is no one right way to do this, but I favor the simple approach where both systems are blissfully unaware of one another and I take steps to keep it that way.

One more thing: if your server needs to run 24x7, remember to ensure windows doesn't try to save your battery by turning itself off to save power.  It happens :)